# Backup new Windows 8.1 system after upgrading from Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, backup, system-recovery

I have [this](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4132&product=5305510&sw_lang=) HP Ultrabook which came with Windows 8 pre-installed.

It had `(OS)C:\` and `(RECOVERY)D:\` Partitions.

Now since **I have upgraded to windows 8.1.**
 **The D:\ RECOVERY partition doesn't make any sense as it has files that would only re-install Windows 8 on performing a recovery in case of system failure,** so I deleted it.

**I don't want to go through the trouble of installing Windows 8 from manufacturer DVDs and then upgrading it to 8.1 as it takes extremely long time (~ 24 Hours Complete).** The Manufacturer's Factory Reset setup itself takes 8 hours and then windows 8.1 update file is very large to be downloaded over my connection in a reasonable time.

I believe it's not possible to re-create the recovery partition with Windows 8.1 System Files using windows tools.
For the time being I have a custom Refresh image created using cmd line tool

`recimg /createimage`

But that's not a full backup I guess. So....
**What are my other options?**

**Also it would be very helpful if some one pointed out what components does the `recimg` tool backup?** Like Does it back up *Program Files, WINDOWS folder, registry, boot partition etc ?*  **What are it's limitation.**

**How will my pc react to a refresh and a reset now ?**

Comment: use any 3rd party backup tool you want like http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx to create a backup + recovery DVD

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a good explanation about what the refresh, reset, or restore options do in Windows 8.1.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc

I had to do a refresh on my Windows 8.1 PC after upgrading, and the process kept my files intact; but deleted all of my desktop apps. My Windows Store apps were reinstalled automatically and the data that was used by those apps wasn't deleted.

Comment: The linked page doesn't address the OP's question at all